# I cant update photo in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this function where I want to update image so I write:
[image]

this line wont work: $request->one give me right image is uploaded just I see this error

[image]

[image]

Comment: You probably need to do `$request->file("one")` to properly access the file. I believe that `$request->one` is shorthand for `$request->input("one")`, which would report the uploaded filename (as a string), but not the actual file. Also, **please don't post code as an image.** Code is text, you can copy and paste it into the question. If we needed to copy your code to test something, it's impossible, since it is an image.

Comment: @TimLewis when i return $request->file("one") its empty !!

Comment: Did you apply the fix below? You can't send a file via a `method="get"` form request. You need to use `POST` (or `PUT`, `PATCH`, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this  change the method to post from get

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('update_slider')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: i change the method to post from get

Comment: Hmm, I see. Well, in the future, why don't you explain what you've changed **inside your answer**? Only putting "Try this:" and the code dump is pretty low-quality, and if you had explained what you changed and why they should try it, then this whole conversation wouldn't be happening.